# How do I perform inline calculations on two variables within an .erb file?

Tags: ruby

I have the following .erb view in a Sinatra app:

```
<% sessions.each do |session| %>
    <%= session.balance_beginning %>
    <%= session.balance_ending %>
<% end %>
```

It works as expected, displaying the beginning and ending balances recorded for each session. I would like to calculate the net balances from within the .erb file, but I can't figure out how to do it. I have tried variations of this:

```
<% sessions.each do |session| %>
    <%= session.balance_ending - session.balance_beginning %>
<% end %>
```

That doesn't work. I receive the following error in Sinatra:

```
undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass
```

How do I do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: First, do not perform calculations in views - extract them to a helper. Second, `session.balance_ending` is `nil`, thus the error.

Comment: @d11wtq: And noting that `nil.to_i` is zero would make it even better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right @Zabba, in this case I think you would add a method to your Session model so you  could call session.net_balance.

Then in your balance_ending and balance_beginning methods you would want to handle nil, either raise an error or return zero if that is valid.